# Recording video stream from Kinect using SDK2.0

Tags: c++, matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk

I recently buy Kinect V2 and I want to record Depth, RGB and Skeleton video stream. For that, I downloaded the SDK2.0 and also I found an example to video the simultaneous 3 channel video stream [Kinect One and Matlab - Data Stream Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700993/kinect-one-and-matlab-data-stream-display)
I am very new to this, so anyone help to explain the steps how can I use that code in Visual Studio 2010? and Do I also need to  install more software's to recode video?

Answer (score 0):

This link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/sensor_setup.aspx) shows the requirements.

This link (http://laht.info/record-3d-video-with-kinect-v2-and-play-it-back-in-the-browser/) provides a very good example on how to save RGB-D stream from Kinect V2.